# Change 'String?' from DropdownFormField to 'String'

Tags: string, flutter, dropdown

In my code, I have this `DropdownFormField` so the user can select their gender:

```
         DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Select gender'),
              validator: (val) => val!.isEmpty ? 'Fill the field' : null,
              isExpanded: true,
              value: _selectedValue,
              items: items.map(buildMenuItem).toList(),
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  gender = val;
                });
              },
            )
```

in `onChanged: (val)`, `val` is expected to be a `String?`, but `gender` is a `String`. is a use `val as String` as `gender = val as String`, apparently it works. But, if I press the save button without selecting an option, I get an error:

> Null check operator used on a null value

As if the item isn"t going through `validator`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `!` operator after a nullable value tells flutter to assume the value is not null and to throw an error if it is.

```
(val) => val!.isEmpty ? 'Fill the field' : null,
```

so when you call this with an empty option, it throws an error because val is null at this point in time. To fix this, simply change the validator to something like this:

```
(val) => (val==null || val.isEmpty) ? 'Fill the field' : null,
```

Also, something else is that there is no need to say `val as String` if your type is `String?`, that is literally the reason why `!` exists, for situations in which you already know a nullable value is not null:

```
gender = val!;
```

Comment: It worked almost flawlessly. Had to maintain gender = val as String, otherwise the text input wasn't being saved.